# Use Ajax.Beginform to send multipart/form-data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post a multipart/form-data to a web API in my view. The code of the view is:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
}

<h2>Upload Image</h2>

<div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(null, null, null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", Url = "http://localhost:59650/api/ingestion/upload", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure", OnBegin = "OnBegin" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <input type="file" name="FileUpload" />
            </li>

            <li>
                @Html.Label("SheetName: ")
                @Html.TextBox("SheetName")
            </li>

            <li>
                @Html.Label("Columns: ")
                @Html.TextBox("Columns")
            </li>

            <li>
                @Html.Label("File Name: ")
                @Html.TextBox("FileName", ViewData["FileName"])
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="upload_btn" value="Upload" />
    </div>
}
</div>

@section Scripts
{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function OnBegin(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
        }

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert("Upload Successfully");
            //TODO:change the location
            window.location.href = "http://localhost:59650/";
        }

        function OnFailure(response) {
            alert("Upload failed, Please try again");
            //TODO:change the location
            window.location.href = "http://localhost:59650/Ingestion/Uploading";
        }

    </script>
}
```

I make the content type to multipart/form-data in the http attributes in the beginform helper method as well as in the ajax call. However, in my api method, I got the exception saying:

```
"Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a 'multipart' content-type header with a 'boundary' parameter.\r\nParameter name: content"
```

My web API in the controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/ingestion")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    QueueClient SenderClient;

    [Authorize]
    /// <summary>
    /// Post request to encrypt and upload file onto Azure blob storage.
    /// Receives value from form-data type with different values such as column, user id, key etc.
    /// Sends the uploaded file details to the ETL service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>IHTTPActionResult either Ok or BadRequest</returns>
    [Route("upload")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostFormData()
    {
        var blob = new BlobUploadModel();

        try
        {
            MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(Path.GetTempPath());
            //I got the exception here
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
            //Do sth
            ...
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }


        return Ok(blob);
    }
}
```

I am very confused about why I am getting this exception. Is there any other ways to send the form to the specific url and handle the response accordingly rather than using the ajax.beginform method?